# If-else in single statement vs loop

Tags: python, syntax-error, google-colaboratory

```
n = int(input())

def factorial(n):
    return 1 if n == 0 else n * factorial(n-1)

factorial(n)
```

> The code above works fine but the code below does not. Help please?

```
n = int(input())

def factorial(n):
    print(n)
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        n * factorial(n-1)

factorial(n)
```

Comment: you are not returning in else

Comment: You're missing a `return` on the last line of the second version of the function, which means it ends up returning `None` and presumably raises a `TypeError` when you try to do `int` things with it.

Comment: Try it again with `return n * factorial(n - 1)`.

Comment: Some naming clarification: There are no loops in your code. The top block uses a [conditional expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) and the bottom block uses a [conditional statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem just return the value inside the else:

```
n = int(input())

def factorial(n):
    print(n)
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

factorial(n)
```